# Dropdown selected after submit , but first time in thisYear

Tags: php, html, forms, dropdown, selected

i have a question. I want to create a dropdown menu with PHP which shows mit the currentYear-2 and currentYear+2. I created the dropdown menu, but after selecting and submitting the year. it start again with the not submitted year.

And i want that if the page is loading the dropdown starts with the current year, and then after changing and submitting with the selected year.

Thanks a lot!

PHP function to get and set the years:

```
function getCurrentYears(){
    $thisYear = date("Y");

    for($i=($thisYear-2); $i<($thisYear+3); $i++){
        echo "<option value='" .$i. "'>" .$i. "</option>";
    }
}
```

HTML where the function is called:

```
<div>
<label for="chooseYear"> Choose a year </label>
     <select name="chooseYear" id="chooseYear" class="form-control">
       <option value='-'>-</option>
       <?php getCurrentYears(); ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: First time the user comes in, add selected from this year to the session. After submit add submitted to session. Then test against year in session: `if ($i === $_SESSION['year']) {
            $selected = 'selected';
        }`

Comment: hi, thanks for the tip. But how can i implement it with the $_SESSION ?

Comment: See the dupe and add the code from the answer below

Comment: which answer do you mean? ^^

Comment: Any of them really. `https://stackoverflow.com/a/61520030/295783`

Comment: the answers are not working, I try them...

Comment: "not working"... Not a useful statement. If you implement their suggestion with my suggestion to use a session it will work

Answer (score 1):

You missed to add the `selected` key to the `select` input.
Also, I recommend you not to mix the view with the PHP code.

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

function getYearsFromRange($yearsRange): array
{
    $currentYear = (int) date('Y');
    $years = [];

    foreach ($yearsRange as $year) {
        $years[] = ['year' => $year, 'selected' => ($year === $currentYear)];
    }

    return $years;
}
```

And the HTML script.

```
<div>
    <label for="chooseYear"> Choose a year </label>
    <select name="chooseYear" id="chooseYear" class="form-control">
        <?php foreach (getYearsFromRange(range(date('Y') - 2, date('Y') + 3))
            as ['year' => $year, 'selected' => $selected]
        ): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $year;?><?php echo ($selected) ? ' selected' : '';?>>
                <?php echo $year; ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $selected = ( $i == $row1['year'] ? ' selected' : '' );
   echo "<option value ='".$i."'".$selected.">".$i."</option>" ;
```

whereas $row1['year'] is the value from the database. This will only work if you are submitting the year in the database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `selected`  or `selected="selected'` in `option` tag

function getCurrentYears(){
            $thisYear = date("Y");

```
  for($i=($thisYear-2); $i<($thisYear+3); $i++){
        if($i == $thisYear){
            echo "<option value='" .$i. "' selected>" .$i. "</option>";
        }
        else{
             echo "<option value='" .$i. "' >" .$i. "</option>";
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: thanks man, but now if i change the year and submit it, for example for 2018 then the dropdown is still 2020, but i need 2018..

Comment: @SHbnkr So store in the session